# Include items in JavaScript array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

i m trying to include some items in the JavaScript arrays that is the id's of the li element.
any suggestions.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javscript">
   var arr=[];
   </script>
  </head>
   <body>
  <ul>
  <li id="index.html"></li>
  <li id="gallery.html" ></li>
  <li id="Contact Us.html"></li>
  </ul>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    var arr = $('li').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var arr = [];
    $('li').each(function(){
      arr.push(this.id);
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = new Array();
    $('li').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```